# Android : to visual an image from drawable folder

Tags: android, drawable

It's possibile to visual an image into drawable folder with android standard visual image application ? I want that when the user application click on the tiny picture the application visual it with android standard visual image program

Comment: Found a solution ? I tried myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.company.app/" + R.drawable.imagenmame)) with no success either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you want to display image in default app. You can try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(imagefilePath)), "image/png");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: `intent.setDataAndType(new Uri("drawable/imagenmame.png"), "image/png");`

Comment: it's say me that is impossibile to find /drawable/imagexxx.png